# facebook graph api get code for exchange of access token using python sdk for facebook

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the code for login so that I can exchange the same  for an access token .I tried using php by going to the redirect url  and its working , I am unable to do the same using python .

My code I tried for getting the code

```
import facebook
import urllib2 as urllib
import requests

app_id='xxx'

app_secret='yyyyyyyyy'

redirect_uri='redirect_for_python_sdk.php'

scopes="public_profile, basic_info , read_friendlists, user_birthday,  user_likes, user_interests, user_education_history,  user_website, user_activities,user_groups,  user_photos,  user_friends"

dialog_url="http://www.facebook.com/dialog?client_id="+app_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&granted_scopes="+scopes


a=urllib.urlopen(dialog_url)
print a.read()
```

Its not giving the output .I also tried what I did using php

```
print ("<script>top.location.href='" + dialog_url + "'</script>")
```

How should I go to the redirect_uri using python so that I can get the code and exchange the same for an access token?
I also browsed through python sdk for facebook .The have implemented functions for getting app access token and exchange code for access token ,but how to get the code using python? please help ..